# HQL / JPA find available items between date range

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

It's car rental app.
I have table:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|id  |start_date  |end_date    |car_id| 
+----+------------+------------+------+  
|1   |2017-04-01  |2017-04-10  |1     |
|2   |2017-04-15  |2017-04-20  |1     |
|3   |2017-04-15  |2017-04-20  |2     |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

Hibernate query for find all available cars between user input 'userDateStart' and 'userDateEnd'.

```
select
b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, b.car.id
from BorrowedDate as b
where :userDateStart not between startDate and endDate
and :userDateEnd not between startDate and endDate

------------
:userDateStart = 2017-04-02 00:00:00
:userDateEnd = 2017-04-10 00:00:00
```

My result is:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|id  |start_date  |end_date    |car_id| 
+----+------------+------------+------+  
|2   |2017-04-15  |2017-04-20  |1     |
|3   |2017-04-15  |2017-04-20  |2     |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

Result is wrong because car with id=1 is borrowed in this time. Only car_id=2 should be available.

Comment: Looks correct to me. It is available on row with id=2

Comment: It's not correct @JackFlamp because car_id=1 in this range of time is unavailable. It's available in the other date. But i would like to have list with cars available in specific range of time from userinput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your query is correct.

But if you want to select based on car id so you should add car id as a condition too into your query

For example

```
SELECT b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, b.car.id
FROM BorrowedDate b
WHERE :userDateStart NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND :userDateEnd NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND b.car.id = :carId
```

OR you can do it like that too

```
SELECT b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, c.id
FROM BorrowedDate b INNER JOIN b.car c
WHERE :userDateStart NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND :userDateEnd NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND c.id = :carId
```

then you have to pass :carId value equals 2

**UPDATE**

you can try this SQL query if you need to get result dynamic, i will update it soon with JPQL

```
SELECT b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, b.car.id
FROM BorrowedDate b
WHERE '2017-04-02 00:00:00' NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND '2017-04-10 00:00:00' NOT BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate
AND b.car.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT bd.car.id FROM BorrowedDate bd WHERE '2017-04-02 00:00:00' BETWEEN bd.startDate AND bd.endDate OR '2017-04-10 00:00:00' BETWEEN bd.startDate AND bd.endDate)
```

HERE are **JPQL** too

```
SELECT model.id, model.startDate, model.endDate, model.car.id
FROM BorrowedDate model
WHERE :userDateStart NOT BETWEEN model.startDate AND model.endDate
AND :userDateEnd NOT BETWEEN model.startDate AND model.endDate
AND model.car.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.car.id FROM BorrowedDate b WHERE :userDateStart BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate OR :userDateEnd BETWEEN b.startDate AND b.endDate)
```

Comment: Your query @mibrahim.iti doesn't work properly. `SELECT b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, b.car.id
FROM BorrowedDate b
WHERE '2017-04-02 00:00:00' >= b.startDate
AND '2017-04-10 00:00:00' <= b.endDate` and result is `|1   |2017-04-01  |2017-04-10  |1     |` where we have id, start_date, end_date, car_id. I would like to have in result list of cars which are available. For this date range i should have available only car with id=2.

Comment: @twistezo yes, i was wrong on something, i edited my answer, actually your main query is right but you missed up the condition of car id

Comment: ok i see, but i don't want search by specific car_id. I would like to have list of all available cars from one query.

Comment: You don't need update this with JPQL because your last answer works great word by word in Hibernate console. So thank you @mibrahim.iti

Comment: @twistezo you are welcome, but i updated it anyway with JPQL, and i think it will be same for HQL too

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a fully overlapping period.  This is the correct logic for full overlaps:

```
select b.id, b.startDate, b.endDate, b.car.id
from BorrowedDate as b
where :userDateStart <= startDate and
      :userDateEnd >= endDate;
```

So, this gets you cars that are rented for the entire period that the customer wants one.  That is probably not your intention.

Let me assume you want cars *available* during the period.  For that, let me assume that you have a `cars` table:

```
select c.*
from cars as c
where not exists (select 1
                  from borrowed b
                  where :userDateStart <= endDate and
                        :userDateEnd >= startDate
                 );
```

Note:  This is standard(ish) SQL.  Hibernate has some  unusual conventions, but the idea should be the same.

Comment: Should looks like this ? `select b.car.id
from Car as c, BorrowedDate as b
where not exists 
(select 1 from b
where '2017-04-02 00:00:00' <= endDate 
and '2017-04-10 00:00:00' >= startDate
)` It's return nothing for me. And what means `select 1` in your query ?

Comment: That would appear to be the correct logic.  The `select 1` is just to select any value and `1` is really easy to type.  It would appear that you have no cars available for that entire period.