# How to design a data model which is having a date range?

Tags: java, spring, entity

In my Spring application I need to design a data model which is having date range. Is there any data type which can be used?

Currently I did something like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scheduled_period")
public class ScheduledPeriod {

    private Date oneDay;

    private Date fromDate;

    private Date toDate;
}
```

I want to put fromDate and toDate together in to something like dateRange

Comment: Use `LocalDate` to represent dates. `Date` represents a datetime and is generally a bad class to use.

Comment: Are you asking for date-only values or date with time-of-day?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is yours, by using **LocalDate**. 
By using two LocalDate to Start Date and End Date.  
and working with them, see: 
[HQL / JPA find available items between date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582169/hql-jpa-find-available-items-between-date-range)

some DBMS's like PostgreSQL has datatype named: **daterange** 
for example:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (room int, during daterange);
INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    (1108, '[2010-01-01 14:30, 2010-01-01 15:30)');
```

but Java (JPA) does not support **datarange** data type. 
If you generate that table into Entity, it generated to Object.

```
private Object during;

public Object getDuring() {
    return this.during;
}
public void setDuring(Object during) {
    this.during = during;
}
```

finally, if you persist to use rangedate, you can define a new class (Entity) named RangeDate with two LocalDates or use array of LocalDate (if your DMBS support it).